# Overlapping instances with type-level naturals in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-level-computation

To make dealing with certain networking protocols, I've been using `GHC.TypeLits` to implement fixed-size bit-vectors as wrapped integers tagged with types of the kind `Nat`.

```
newtype W (n :: Nat) = W { getW :: Integer }
```

Along with instances for all sorts of classes (Integral, Num, Bits, etc), I've defined a function to combine them:

```
(>+<) :: forall n m. (KnownNat m, KnownNat n, KnownNat (m + n)) => W m -> W n -> W (m + n)
(W x) >+< (W y) = fromInteger $ x + shift y (natValInt (Proxy :: Proxy m))
```

This next part is where I'm having trouble. I am attempting to create an applicative that results in a `W n` from one that results in a `W m`, where `m` is a divisor of `n`. For example, using attoparsec, should be able to write:

```
anyWord128 :: Parser (W 128)
anyWord128 = assemble $ fmap (fromIntegral :: Word8 -> W 8) anyWord8
```

Here is my attempt:

```
class (KnownNat d, KnownNat n) => d :|: n where
    assemble :: forall f. Applicative f -> f (W d) -> f (W n)

instance KnownNat n => n :|: n where
    assemble = id

instance (KnownNat n, CmpNat n d ~ GT, d :|: n', (d + n') ~ n) => d :|: n where
    assemble f = liftA2 (>+<) f (assemble f)
```

The code compiles (with many language extensions, including -XOverlappingInstances, all of which are in the actual source linked below), loading the example usage of `assemble` causes GHCi to tell me that there are overlapping instances for `8 :|: 8`. I am guessing that this either because I don't know what I am doing or because of GHC's type-checker's limited computational abilities (or both).

Do any of you GHC wizards see a way of defining this class correctly?

**Edit**

Fixed type in definition of assemble - thanks kosmikus.
Also, here is the full [source](https://github.com/nickspinale/bigword/blob/master/Data/BigWord.hs) (`:|:` is defined on line 159).

Comment: Could you actually present code that compiles? There are lots of missing imports/definitions, and also typos (`c` in last line not in scope, `Applicative f ->` ...). Nevertheless: the two instances you give a clearly overlapping; but doesn't it just work with `OverlappingInstances`?

Comment: My apologies - the original definition of accumulate had an extra parameter of the same type as (>+<) to allow accumulation in both directions (meaning it could be passed both `(>+<)` and `flip (>+<)`. Also, I've linked the full [source](https://github.com/nickspinale/bigword/blob/master/Data/BigWord.hs), which includes imports and extensions. Unfortunately, -XOverlappingInstances is already there.

Comment: @nick: The link you provided has a different definition of `assemble` and doesn't have OverlappingInstances.

Comment: Wow - I feel pretty dumb right now. I somehow recall having tried -XOverlappingInstances (perhaps I did, in a previous version), and thought I still had it in that massive stack of pragmas. Thank you both for you help, and sorry for posting such a silly question...

Comment: @nick: No problem, it was an interesting exercise to deduce "n must divide into m" when I missed that part of the question and tried to grok your instance.

Comment: So is there anything to answer here now?

Comment: Nope :(. Should I do something to delete the question?